# What time is it again?

Tags: popularity-contest, graphical-output, date

#### [The Inspiration](http://ubaydinoyatov.github.io/clockclock/)

### The Challenge

I'm tired of seeing the same old-same old clock in my top-right-hand corner of my screen. It's time for a new clock. While the clock clock sated my lack of interesting clock for a little while, it simply will do no longer. Your job: make a better, more interesting clock.

### The Rules

Make a clock, provided that:

- Output is either graphical or directed to STDOUT or equivalent.
- You do not use ASCII numbers as the output (don't just print out the time).
- It must run continuously until stopped by closing the window or by CTRL-C or equivalent.
- It may NOT print out an infinite amount of lines (if using STDOUT).
- It must be human-readable, in any way.
- It must be accurate to 1/10th of a second to the system clock, and update with any changes to the system clock (so if I change system settings, it will update to my system clock).
- Your program cannot exceed 1024 bytes.

### Pop-con Objectives

The voters should keep in mind the following:

- #### Creativity should be valued above all.
- The better the explanation, the greater the up-votes.

Comment: You are saying it has to be accurate to 1/10 of a second of the system clock. Do we have to include those in the output or is hh:mm:ss enough?

Comment: @DenkerAffe HH:MM:SS is enough, however, it should be verifiable with the system clock. Debug version would be awesome. :)

Comment: This has two issues: 1. *It must be a human-readable clock* is not an objective validity criterion. 2. The primary voting criterion is *creativity*, making the challenge too broad.

Comment: *sigh* I wish these considerations had been brought up in the sandbox. Oh, well.

Answer (score 9):

### Bash

```
watch -tn.1 date +%T\|figlet
```

Yeah, yeah, I know it's not golf (28 bytes!), but I do like the minimalism:

[image: animated gif demo]

`watch` is a tool provided by the `procps` package that repeatedly runs a command every <specified interval of time> and outputs the updated results. (An example of where this is handy: `watch -n.1 ls -lh ~/downloads/foo` to view the progress of a download.)

The `-t` flag for `watch` represents `--no-title`, as otherwise it would look like this:

[image: screenshot of watch without -t]

The `-n 0.1` flag simply means "update every 0.1 seconds."

Then comes the command that we're `watch`ing over. First, `date +%T` prints the date in the desired format (`date` comes from coreutils):

```
       %T     time; same as %H:%M:%S
```

Then this is piped to `figlet` (unsurprisingly provided by the `figlet` package), which converts STDIN to ASCII art.

```
(|  |  _            _   _,            _|   _  
 |  | / \_|  |     /   / |  /|/|     / |  / \_
  \/|/\_/  \/|_/   \__/\/|_/ | |_/   \/|_/\_/ 
   (|                                         

             _/  _/                                      _/                
    _/_/_/  _/  _/        _/_/_/    _/_/    _/  _/_/  _/_/_/_/    _/_/_/   
 _/    _/  _/  _/      _/_/      _/    _/  _/_/        _/      _/_/        
_/    _/  _/  _/          _/_/  _/    _/  _/          _/          _/_/     
 _/_/_/  _/  _/      _/_/_/      _/_/    _/            _/_/  _/_/_/        


        _|                   |    |   |    _)                  
  _ \  |    __ \   _ \  _` | __|  __| __ \  | __ \   _` |  __| 
 (   | __|  |   |  __/ (   | |    |   | | | | |   | (   |\__ \ 
\___/ _|   _|  _|\___|\__,_|\__| \__|_| |_|_|_|  _|\__, |____/ 
                                                   |___/       
                       _                                
    o_|_|_  _|_|_  _  |_o _ | __|_ ._ .__  _ .__.._ _   
\/\/| |_| |  |_| |(/_ | |(_||(/_|_ |_)|(_)(_||(_|| | |o 
                          _|       |       _|
```

Comment: Hmm. Figlet. *goes off to run `apt-get install figlet`* I like.

Comment: Are you sure this doesn't violate the requirement not to print an infinite number of lines?